# IOError Django Permission Denied

Tags: python, django

I want to watermark every image a user upload on my Django site. I decided to install a package [Django-watermark](https://github.com/codekoala/django-watermark) to handle the operation. After installing and carrying out all the necessary settings, I launched the page to check if it works..after visiting the page, I'm getting the below error. I'm on Windows machine (Windows 7) . I granted the media folder full permission by visiting Properties->Security->Edit, and I clicked on full control for every group and usernames.

I visited the page again, and I'm still getting the same error.

```
IOError at /ham/5/

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\nate\\media'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ham/5/
Django Version:  1.4
Exception Type:  IOError
Exception Value:  

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\nate\\media'

Exception Location:  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open, line 1952
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:    2.7.3
```

How can I get rid of this? I'm in development server(Django and Wampserver).

Comment: Is `nate` is your django project?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to [give the directory](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed) write access for whichever user django is running under.

Comment: I've done that. I even right clicked on the nate folder itself and grant user full control yet I'm still getting the same error.